# Find $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{(x^2+y)^2}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{(x^2+y)^2}{x^2+y^2}$$

I have looked at:

$$\lim_{(x,0)\to (0,0)}\frac{(x^2)^2}{x^2}=\lim_{(x,0)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^4}{x^2}=\lim_{(x,0)\to (0,0)}x^2=0$$

And at:
$$\lim_{(0,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{(x^2+y)^2}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{(0,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{y^2}{y^2}=1$$

So there is no limit, but are there other paths to show there is no limit?

Comment: $x=0$, $y=mx$ for $m \neq 0$? :p

Comment: You can take x=my for some m. And see if limit is depended on m or not.

Comment: There are infinitely many paths. But once you've produced two of them such that the limits aren't the same along them that pair is enough to conclude that the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

plugging $$x=1/n,y=1/\sqrt{n}$$ in the given term we obtain
$$\frac{n^2+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}(1+n)}$$ and this tends to infinity for $n$ tends to infinity, thus there is no limit

Answer (score 0):

along the curve

$$x (t)=\sqrt {t} $$
$$y (t)=\sqrt {t}-t $$

$$f (x (t),y (t))=\frac {1}{2-2\sqrt {t}+t} $$
goes to $\frac 12$.

Comment: Although there is no limit?

Comment: @gbox It is just an other path.